# Read Paths and load data in the paths and also capture path details in the dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am reading multiple paths and loading the parquet files in those paths using the below commands:

```
val paths = List("/mnt/datamount/tmp/fldr=2345","/mnt/datamount/tmp/fldr=1234","/mnt/datamount/tmp/fldr=5678")
```

Below is the read command:

```
val readdf = spark.read.format("parquet").load(paths: _*)
```

this reads all the parquet files in the paths mentioned with the below structure:

```
col1: String
col2: Int
col3: Long
```

Is there any way I can capture the path info and add the value to the dataframe? The structure would be like below

```
col1: String
col2: Int
col3: Long
fldr: Int
```

With spark's partition discovery it would be able to capture it by putting the base path but there are 40000 partitions and it takes time to read. Using the above method I am able to read the files in seconds but unable to capture the folder information in the dataframe which is need downstream for joins with other dataframes!

Comment: Your paths contain both `fldr1` and `fldr3`. But your schema contains `fldr`. Does that mean you don't care about the actual column name in the path and just want to merge them into 1 column?

Comment: i have edited the path..fldr would be the column name

Answer (score 0):

You could read every path separately so you can manually add the extra column, and then take the union of all those dataframes.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

def extractFldrFromPath(path: String): String = ???
def readPath(path: String): DataFrame = {
  val fldr = extractFldrFromPath(path)
  val df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(path)
  df.withColumn("fldr", lit(fldr))
}

paths.map(readPath).reduce(_ union _)
```

Comment: i had done this using for loop but was trying to see if there was anyway we can read all the paths that existed at once!

Comment: Have you measured that it makes a difference?